# What does "bang in" and "bang out of" mean here?

Tags: meaning, phrases

*Kids and dogs bang in and out of the dazzling hot day.*

Comment: Think of a door banging closed as kids incessantly go in and out.

Comment: I agree with @Robusto. Additionally, kids and dogs running around make a lot of noise. They may knock things over causing banging noises or throw objects around.

Comment: Also, the day is "dazzling"ly hot, so the door would be a screen door with a spring that automatically closes it with a bang. The farther it opens, the louder the bang. And children, with all the energy of youth, go through the door at such speed that all its closings are at maximum volume.